# Extern Reports generate parallel test report not in beauty order

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

When I execute test cases sequentially, the test report generated from ExternReports is correct. With each test pass and fail described. But when I try to execute test cases parallelly, almost all test cases are passed even failed test cases. The only test case that failed is the last test, and when I click on it, it shows multiple fails of other failed test but is marked as Pass.

[This is the report of sequen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVLpX.jpg)
[This is the report of parallel test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhS41.jpg)

For how I implement my test to run parallel, I run test parallel by Parallelizable in NUnit framework.
`[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]`
And the web driver is declare as ThreadLocal
`public ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>();`

I expect my test report of parallel to be similar to sequently.